# Are questions about compiler design suitable for SO?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions about compiler design suitable for SO?  For example, I have questions regarding (among other things) the design of abstract syntax trees and optimization strategies.  These questions aren't programming language specific.  Should I take these questions to the Theoretical Computer Science community instead?

Comment: These are better suited for [cs.se] rather than [cstheory.se].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem with using SO for questions like these is that the community expects questions to be:

1. Specific,
2. Demonstrating prior research effort, and
3. Answerable in a few paragraphs or less.

Anything that veers into tutoring or teaching a topic, or looks like a discussion, is generally discouraged, with a few notable exceptions.